# Protect Excel Spreadsheet with a macro when a condition is satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a spreadsheet that has SOME read-only (protected) columns.

I would like to have a macro that will run when the user ticks a box on that sheet, this macro will protect the rest of the coluns demming the whole sheet protected (read-only).

It doesn't have to be ticking a box, but I want them to indicate to the spreadsheet: "I am finished, freeze!"

Comment: [Take a look at some of these replies.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80796-how-set-readonly-visual-basic-applications.html#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this, although there are probably better ways to do it.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="yourpassword", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

To unprotect the sheet maybe put:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("yourpassword")
```

When the sheet is activated or when you open the workbook.

Hope this helps.